# Rails: Uploading Images to Amazon S3 via Carrierwave only works on "Edit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, amazon-s3, carrierwave

(An Image belongs to a Post)

The image uploader works, but only when I upload the image on Post Edit. I want the image to upload as the Post is created.

The Image upload ("<%= f.file_field :image %>") is within the New Post Form, so I'm guessing Carrierwave is trying to upload the image to the designated path before the Post is created, causing it to not know where to upload.

Here is the ImageUploader file:

```
class TrackImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def cache_dir
   "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end

 include CarrierWave::RMagick

 #storage :file
 #storage :fog

 def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
 end

 version :featured do
   process :resize_to_fill => [210, 145]
 end

 def extension_white_list
   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
 end
end
```

I am guessing the store_dir from the code above is in charge of saving the image in the according path on Amazon S3.

How would I make it so that it uploads the image AFTER the Post is made, so that it can get the Post.id ?

Comment: Could you post the model code as well?

Comment: @John Here you go: https://gist.github.com/2994293 thanks!

Comment: Hmm, you could try playing with the AR callbacks in your model to see if forcing a save helps with anything. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: eventually, if your code is hosted on github on any other similar site, could you give us a link of your app so we can try playing with it and find the problem ?

Comment: http://onvard.com/curators_guide - this is the site. you would just click on the green button and upload an image inside there. Currently the images do upload, but is all distorted. But when we edit the track and upload the same image, the image is sized to fit perfectly. strange..

Comment: Can you show us your controller code? This really depends on how you are handling the incoming form post.

Comment: @regulatethis Here you go! https://gist.github.com/4274025

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, but I've found a solution.

My ImageUploader.rb looks like this: https://gist.github.com/egbertp/7572501. On line 9 of this file you'll see `include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader`. By using the direct uploader technique, your site-user will upload his/her file directly to the Rackspace cloud. However, at the time of uploading, the Image model is not yet created in you database, causing an error (as you guessed correctly).

By disabling the direct upload technique, the site-user sends the image to your webserver fist and afterwards the Image model is created and saved in the database. In my ImageUploader class this is also necessary because I would like my webserver to process the image, in order to create a thumbnail version.

I hope this will help you, or somebody else in the future.

Best regards,
Egbert

Answer (score 0):

I ve also done the same but i ve used the cloudinary gem to maintain my images. Can you please show me ur controller where u ve written the edit action.
I m showing you my code u can tally it with urs

in the controller in edit action

```
def create
 @img = Image.new(params[:img])
  if @img.save
    redirect_to(:action => 'show')
  else
    render('c_view')
  end
end
```

in the view from where it is taking the image

```
<%= form_for :img, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f| %>
 <%= f.label "Upload an image"%>
    <%= f.hidden_field(:image_cache)%>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>      

 <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-success"%>
    <% end %>
```

To show the image in some view page ive used this

```
<% @img.each_with_index do |i|%>    
     <%= image_tag (i.image.url) %>
<%end%>
```